# How to set another field in show table instead of the id in relationships fields in Laravel BackPack?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have an issue here, I have an entity that contains relationships only, and I need to show in the table generated by backpack crud another field of the entity instead of the id, check it out in the picture below:

[image]

For instance, the President is a user, and I want to show the Name of that user instead of the id, is there any way to achieve this?, thanks.

Bests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 to n relation use [select](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-select) column type.

For n t n relation use [select_multiple](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-select_multiple) column type.

Hope it help you to find right solution :)

Comment: How to do this in select2 ?